# zf2 LoginServiceInterface interaction with model

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am new to ZF2 and I am studying the Services and ServiceManager. I want to make an "authentication" via an API (http://127.0.0.1/api/login) and I need to interact also with the DB in the same time. I will have some data from the API after login plus another dat I will get some other data from DB.

I have a LoginController who has a login method with

> $test = $this->loginService->login($username, $password);

I created a login service with another login method:

> $apiService = new ApiService();
>
> $userApi = $apiService->postRequest('login/', ['email'=>$username, 'password'=>$password]);

The calls on the API I've put in another service (ApiService).

First question is how can i do in order to not depend on ApiService? i have a service that depends on another one
Second question is how to mix the api data with the db data in this LoginService? is it a best practice to inject the model in the Factory and make calls to it in the Service?

The flow, in my head, should be like this:
LoginController -> LoginService -> API call -> LoginService -> DB -> LoginService -> LoginController -> views or something else.

I know that the login via API is not a best practice because I am not doing that with a authorization framework but for the moment it's easy just to call the endpoint and get the full json.

Thank you for you answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could encapsulate the login functionality by creating any number of services that implement a new interface, perhaps `LoginServiceInterface`. This interface would define the actual methods needed for authentication and the concrete classes would implement them.

The interface could look like this.

```
interface LoginServiceInteface
{
    public function login($username, $password);    
}
```

A concrete implementation could then define the login method.

```
class ApiLoginService implements LoginServiceInterface
{
    protected $dbAdapter;
    protected $apiService;

    public function __construct(ApiServiceInterface $apiService, Adapter $dbAdapter)
    {
        $this->dbAdapter  = $dbAdapter;
        $this->apiService = $apiService;
    }

    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        // do some queries.
        //$this->dbAdapter->query('')...

        $response = $this->apiService->makeSomeCallToApi([$username, $password]);

        if ($response) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You would also need to register the class with the service manager and create a service factory to inject the dependencies.